# img::after disappeared when src changed

Tags: html, css

This is a part of my React Code

.jsx code

```
<img draggable={false} data-score={-1 * score} src={AddressConfig.fileServer + "?id=" + photos} onError={this.onError} style={{display:'inline-block'}}/> 
......
onError = (e) => {
        e.target.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/...........'//valid img url
    }
```

.css code

```
img::after{
        content:attr(data-score);
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        height: 15px;
        width:15px;
    }
```

when the onerror event not fired, everything is fine,but when it fired,the `::after` element will disappear. I'm really confused about this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:after` and `:before` are not supported by `img` elements.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter#Caveats

> The pseudo-elements generated by `::before` and `::after` are contained by the element's formatting box, and thus `::before` and `::after` don't apply to **replaced elements** such as `img`, or to `br` elements.